# Cannot start up selenium chromedriver in multiple threads

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, debian

I'm trying to start up my absolutely perfectly working (on windows) code on server. Server is on Debian 11. I keep getting a lot of different errors (they can even be different every time I run the code without changing anything), but the most common is:

```
Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55cacb8b6d33 <unknown>
#1 0x55cacb573f87 <unknown>
#2 0x55cacb5ab87e <unknown>
#3 0x55cacb5a84de <unknown>
#4 0x55cacb5f8a90 <unknown>
#5 0x55cacb5ed0e3 <unknown>
#6 0x55cacb5b5044 <unknown>
#7 0x55cacb5b644e <unknown>
#8 0x55cacb87b861 <unknown>
#9 0x55cacb87f785 <unknown>
#10 0x55cacb869285 <unknown>
#11 0x55cacb88041f <unknown>
#12 0x55cacb84d20f <unknown>
#13 0x55cacb8a4028 <unknown>
#14 0x55cacb8a41f7 <unknown>
#15 0x55cacb8b5ed4 <unknown>
#16 0x1466c9716ea7 start_thread
```

The second most common:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/var/www/joyeria/joyeria.jewelry/image/catalog/productsimage/beta.py", line 16, in work
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=driver_options)
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/www/joyeria/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace:
#0 0x564c78203d33 <unknown>
#1 0x564c77ec0f87 <unknown>
#2 0x564c77ef7c70 <unknown>
#3 0x564c77ef54de <unknown>
#4 0x564c77f45a90 <unknown>
#5 0x564c77f3a0e3 <unknown>
#6 0x564c77f02044 <unknown>
#7 0x564c77f0344e <unknown>
#8 0x564c781c8861 <unknown>
#9 0x564c781cc785 <unknown>
#10 0x564c781b6285 <unknown>
#11 0x564c781cd41f <unknown>
#12 0x564c7819a20f <unknown>
#13 0x564c781f1028 <unknown>
#14 0x564c781f11f7 <unknown>
#15 0x564c78202ed4 <unknown>
#16 0x14faadad0ea7 start_thread
```

but you should mostly pay attention to the first one.

I'm multithreading chromedriver using concurrent.futures

The code works perfectly on Windows and Ubuntu

Here's my init function:

```
def initialize_driver(proxy):
    driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", MANIFEST_JSON)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js())
        driver_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    # driver_options.binary_location = "/var/www/joyeria/joyeria.jewelry/image/catalog/productsimage/chromedriver"
    driver_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") 
    # driver_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
    driver_options.add_argument('--enable-automation')
    driver_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    driver_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    driver_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    driver_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # driver_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')
    # driver_options.add_argument("--dns-prefetch-disable")
    # driver_options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
    # driver_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    # driver_options.add_argument(f"crash-dumps-dir={os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/Crashpad')}")
    driver_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    # driver_options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
    # driver_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    driver_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

    chromedriver_path = "/var/www/joyeria/joyeria.jewelry/image/catalog/productsimage/chromedriver"

    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=driver_options)

    driver.maximize_window()
    
    return driver
```

P.S. All the options commented are the options I tried adding, but they didn't do anything or I used them incorrectly

Here's how i start my threads:

```
threads = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=avialable_threads) as executor:
        for store in store_links:
            threads.append(executor.submit(process_main, store, store_links, global_links, global_pass_links, threads_number))
            
        for thread in threads:
            try:
                thread.result()
            except Exception as exception:
                print(exception)
```

I tried adding different chrome options and changing the way I set the chromedriver path

Comment: There could be many causes for this error.... but you should be careful when it comes to .quit() method.  With multiple threads, a new browser/driver pair can launch when a previous driver is quitting... while the browser is cleaning up directories (one of them holding the session ID that the driver uses) you should avoid starting a new thread.  Since you have no knowledge of when the browser is done cleaning up, you should use a bit of sleep between quitting one driver and starting a new one.  With multiple threads this requires notifying the main thread when a driver quits.

Comment: This sort of error can also be thrown when too many threads are running and resources start running out.  Everything slows down and that file with the session ID doesn't drop in time or the browser fails to startup in time.